# g++ compiling option

Tags: c++, g++, dev-c++

What are options for compile .cpp file into .s and .o without linking it.

I used g++ -s -c but it only produced .o file.

g++ -s with create undefined reference to main (because it a class implementation not a main)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to generate asm files is `-S`, capital S on gcc (you were using `-s`).

Comment: We all have been there, don't worry ;)